# How to select Highvalues of the candlestick with data source

Tags: activex, teechart

I always see the code as `datasource="series0"`.

If `series(0)` is a candlestick and I want to use `Highvalues` or `Closevalues` of the candlestick, how so I select that data? Something like `datasource="series0.Highvalues"?` (It's worth noting that I use teechart2011 Eval and VB6).

If `series(1)` is the financial function `ExpMovAvg`, how to define the width of the `ExpMovAvg` line with code?

Similarly how do I use the `Closevalues` in `Series(0)` for this function? Not merely `datasource="series0"`. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> I always see the code as datasource="series0", if series(0) is a candlestick and I want to use Highvalues or Closevalues of the candlestick,how to select that data? datasource="series0.Highvalues"? (I use teechart2011 Eval and VB6)

Here you have a simple example in VB6. You can assign any of the 4 ValueLists in the Candle series (Open, Close, High, Low) to the be used by the function with the `MandatoryValueList.ValueSource` property:

```
  TChart1.AddSeries scCandle
  TChart1.Series(0).FillSampleValues

  TChart1.AddSeries scLine
  TChart1.Series(1).SetFunction tfExpMovAvg
  TChart1.Series(1).DataSource = TChart1.Series(0)
  TChart1.Series(1).MandatoryValueList.ValueSource = "Close" '"Open" "High" "Low"
```

> if series(1) is the financial function ExpMovAvg, how to define the
>   width of the ExpMovAvg line with code?

You can set the series' `Pen.Width` property as follows:

```
  TChart1.Series(1).Pen.Width = 2
```

> Similarly how to use the Closevalues in Series(0) for this function?
>   not merely datasource="series0", thanks !

This is the same above, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kindly quick reply which is also very helpful to me!! All your code works well!!!